# Molpro - Simple explanation of OCC, CORE, FROZEN and CLOSED orbitals

Tags: orbitals, electronic-configuration, software

I'm beginning with quantum chemistry and I'm supposed to do some ab initio calculations with Molpro. The problem is, I don't understand the orbital specification very well.

Let's say, I have the following computation:

```
 {mrci;
  occ,4,2,2,0,4,2,2,0;
  core,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0;                                                                       
  wf,13,5,1;
  state,3;
  option,nstati=5;
  option,maxit=200;
  option,maxiti=200;
 }
```

I don't understand much the flags `OCC`, `CORE`, `CLOSED` and `FROZEN`. I've read about them in [the documentation](https://www.molpro.net/info/2015.1/doc/manual/node38.html), but I have troubles understanding it. Moreover, they possess different meaning in different methods, i.e. `MCSCF` and `MRCI`.

Could you, please, explain it in a basic way and graphically, if possible? I'm not looking for the deep understanding of methods now (I'll study them later), but I need to be able to use Molpro for some simple (di/tri-atomic) systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MCSCF we have:

- `occ` are occupied orbitals, it refers to all orbitals that may be occupied in any configuration. For a FCI calculation this equals the total number of orbitals (per IRREP). If `occ` is smaller than that, the difference will be the number of virtual (unoccupied) orbitals. Virtual orbitals are never occupied in all the configurations.
- `closed` orbitals are doubly occupied in all configurations. This means `occ` - `closed` equals the number of active orbitals. `closed` orbitals are optimized in an MCSCF calculation.
- `frozen` is similar to `closed`, but they are not optimized in MCSCF, i.e. their MO coefficients will be kept fixed.

In MRCI there are:

- `occ` and `closed` being similar to MCSCF. They are used to define the *reference space* of configurations.
- Multi-reference means additional *external* configurations are created by excitations from the *reference space*. Here excitations from `closed` orbitals are considered, but not from `core` orbitals. In other words: `closed` orbitals are only doubly occupied in the reference space but may have different occupations in the external configurations, while `core` orbitals are doubly occupied in both, the reference space and external configurations.
- `frozen` is not used here, as orbitals are not optimized anyway.

The "lower" set of orbitals is always included in the "higher" set, e.g. `occ` includes all `closed`. Thus we always have `core`/`frozen` <= `closed` <= `occ` <= total number of orbitals.

Here is a graphic for the MRCI case. The curved arrows to the left indicate considered (black) and neglected (red) external excitations into the virtual orbital space. For MCSCF replace `core` with `frozen` and ignore the curved arrows.

[image: orbital spaces in Molpro]

One more note: The picture shows only excitations into the virtual space. But in principle you could also have excitations from closed to active orbitals.

Comment: Text only answer for now, I will try to make a graphic later.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! And I'll be grateful for the pictures.

Comment: @Eenoku I added an orbital diagram to show the different orbital spaces.